# select() and non-blocking recv with dynamic buffer on C

Tags: c, sockets, blocking, nonblocking

I'm trying to figure out why recv is blocking in the code below, if I telnet and send a 'GET / HTTP/1.1', recv keeps waiting for data and blocks another telnet connection as well. However, it works fine and doesn't block if I just use a fixed buffer instead of the `do{} while`, i.e.,

```
char buffer[1024];
nbytes = recv(i, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
```

What I understand so far, `select()` at that point is in a ready-to-read state. Do I need to set `recv` to `O_NONBLOCK`?

```
char *buffer = NULL;
unsigned long LEN = 200;
unsigned long bytes_received = 0;
unsigned long cur_size = 0;
int status = 0;

FD_SET(listener, &master);
fdmax = listener;

for(;;){
    read_fds = master; // copy it
    if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1){
        exit(4);
    }   

    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++){
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)){
            if(i == listener){
                // handle new connections
                addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);

                if(newfd == -1){
                    perror("accept");
                }else{
                    FD_SET(newfd, &master);
                    if(newfd > fdmax) { 
                        fdmax = newfd;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                do{
                    if(bytes_received >= cur_size){
                        char * tmp;
                        cur_size += LEN;
                        tmp = realloc(buffer, cur_size);
                        buffer = tmp;
                    }
                    status = recv(i, buffer + bytes_received, LEN, 0); 
                    if(status == 0){ 
                        printf("Done\n");
                    }
                    else if(status > 0){ 
                        bytes_received += status;
                    }
                    else{
                        fprintf(stderr, "socket error\n");
                    }
                } while (status > 0); 
                if(send(i, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) == -1){
                    perror("send");
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any call to setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_NONBLOCK, ...) that would set your socket(s) to non-blocking.  Is that omitted in your example or actually missing from your program?

Comment: It is not set to `SO_NONBLOCK`, I thought the select() would handle it. Thanks.

Comment: If `select()` had any such magical effect it would say so in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to set the socket non-blocking if you don't want to block. No matter what you do, it is not possible to assure that you never block if your socket operations are blocking. This is a commonly-made mistake that has caused serious bugs with significant security implications. If you must not block, you must set the socket non-blocking.

> What I understand so far, select() at that point is in a ready-to-read state.

You mean *was* in a ready-to-read state. The `select` function is a status-reporting function and, like other status-reporting functions, it reports the status as of some point in-between when you called it and when it returned. There is no guarantee that is still the status at some later point.

Do not ever think you can rule out every other possible way the status might change. History is filled with people who thought that and got burned.

But the specific reason that you are blocking is that you are calling `recv` without first calling `select` (because you have a `do` loop that calls `recv` again).

No matter what, you must correctly handle a `WOULDBLOCK` indication from `recv`. That is essential.

In addition, you may wish to call `recv` only once per `select` hit. If you fix the other issues, it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it's more clear now. One thing I still don't get is why recv hangs even after sending a `GET / HTTP/1.1`through telnet?  Shouldn't this tell recv that data is available?

Comment: It does, then you call `recv` and get the data. But then your `do` loop calls `recv` again. Since the socket is blocking, it blocks until data is available. You must set the socket non-blocking and handle a `WOULDBLOCK` indication from `recv`, and that will fix the problem in all cases. But you may also wish to eliminate the `do` loop and call `recv` only once per `select` hit to fix the problem in the common case.